# The origin of the Wilkinson-style notation such as (1|id) for random effects in mixed models formulae in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, notation, history

[Model formulae](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) in R such as

```
y ~ x + a*b + c:d
```

are based on the so called *Wilkinson notation*: [Wilkinson and Rogers 1973, Symbolic Description of Factorial Models for Analysis of Variance](http://jstor.org/stable/2346786).

This paper did not discuss notations for mixed models (which might not have existed back then). So where did the mixed model formulae used in `lme4` and related packages in R such as

```
y ~ x + a*b + c:d + (1|school) + (a*b||town)
```

come from? Who introduced them for the first time, and when? Is there any agreed upon term such as "Wilkinson notation" for them? I am specifically referring to the terms like

```
(model formula |  grouping variable)
(model formula || grouping variable)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The notation `|` has been around in `nlme` docs since version 3.1-1 and that is probably late 1999; we can easily check that on CRAN [nlme](https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/nlme/) code archive. `nlme` does use this notation, for example try `library(nlme); formula(Orthodont)`; the `|` comes up - so 2000's are off. So let's dig.... "[Graphical Methods for Data with Multiple Levels of Nesting](http://ect.bell-labs.com/sl/project/nlme/JSM97.ps)" Pinheiro & Bates (1997) where the `groupedData` constructor is introduced. And they say: "*The formula in a grouped data object has the same pattern as the formula used in a call to a Trellis graphics function in S-PLUS, such as xyplot*" Which.... makes sense as are P&B working in... Bell Labs (RIP) which developed the Trellis graphics system which actually used the operator `|` already to indicate groups. Which probably means... "[The Visual Design and Control of Trellis Display](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/274a/f5a1ec13bbf9389d04f614906bd61b73ddd1.pdf)" by Becker et al. (1996) has something to do with this. Notation is not introduced in this paper but it is the first electronic Trellis display reference I can find.

Essentially we need to dig-up visualisation literature at this point. Probably I would check Cleveland's book *Visualizing Data* (1993) and early works of Deepayan Sarkar (who developed `lattice`). Notice that the actual operator `|`  (and `||`) are true primitive operators as they are associated with `OR` operators, so it was just a matter of time till someone overloads them.
While not a full answer, I strongly suspect P&B checked their colleagues cool visualisation system (the plots in that 1996 paper are quite good for late 2010's standards) and realised that someone (Becker, Cleveland and Shyu) already did some work on this (maybe even discussed this with them at the time) and just followed up what was already there. I.e. the `|` operator  originates in graphics notation. Trellis almost certainly used it; potential predecessors of Trellis may have done so too but their e-footprint is very hard to track.

In general, I think you might want this page on [NLME: Software for mixed-effects models](http://ect.bell-labs.com/sl/project/nlme/index.html) by Bell Labs for more historic information on `nlme`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's true that `nlme` uses `|` but I don't think it uses `()` to denote random effects, right? Random effects are listed as a separate argument to the function call. Was it `lme4` that introduced `(x|id)` as part of the *same* formula?

Comment: I think you are reading a bit too much into the presence of the parentheses; I strongly suspect they exist for parsing purposes given `lme4` uses a unified syntax for all terms. For example `fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~  Days | Subject, sleepstudy)` works fine without any parenthesis.

Comment: Oh. Indeed. Never thought about it this way :)

Comment: Bates just confirmed that the random part was introduced by the nlme authors (of which he is one): https://twitter.com/BatesDmbates/status/1111283948615802881

Comment: @JonasLindeløv: Cool! Thanks for sharing, I will make a link to the answer tomorrow night.