# how standard is R model formula notation

Tags: regression, notation, history

I like using R model formula notation such as $Y \sim X_1 + X_2$ when thinking of regression relationships at a high level. The same for lmer notation such as  $Y \sim X | group$. I am wondering how standard it is. Does it show up in journal articles? If it is R or S's or lmer's innovation, I probably would not put it in published work, but maybe R/lmer just borrowed it from older statistical practice.

Comment: I think I recall seeing it in a few articles, but much more common is to actually specifically state your assumptions, such as $\mathbf{y}\sim\mathrm{N}(\mathbf{x}^\top\beta,\sigma^2)$ or $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{y}]=\mathbf{x}^\top\beta$.

Comment: @JohnMadden I see that more too, but sometimes I don't want to suggest a parametric family or even linearity or anything else about the form of the regression. Just dependent variable, independent variables, and maybe clustering.

Comment: There's still a specific mathematical expression for that: "$\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x})$ for {differentiable; Lipschitz continuous; bounded; additive; general,...} $f$" :)

Comment: It's not obvious to me, who's not the world's biggest R user, that $Y\sim X_1+X_2$ doesn't imply linearity (or at least additivity).

Comment: @JohnMadden You may be right as I'm struggling to think of examples where it doesn't imply additivity after some transformations

Comment: R's 'formula' model notation is based on an established notation (but extends and modifies it somewhat). Are you seeking a reference for the notation it's based on, that you might include in a paper where you use that notation? There's some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313109/is-there-a-better-reference-for-r-formulas-than-formula/16313110#16313110

Comment: For discussion of the extension to mixed models, see this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284913/the-origin-of-the-wilkinson-style-notation-such-as-1id-for-random-effects-in  ... which traces the use of "|" back through several references to Cleveland's work on graphics. Note that variations on  'Wilkinson notation' are not unique to R -- e.g. see https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wilkinson-notation.html

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks this is actually the answer I was looking for. I see that the notation has an established usage outside of R but that usage is in the data visualization/graphics rather than mainstream statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assume it's standard. Users of S-plus and R would be familiar with it, Julia’s packages adopted it, Python’s statsmodels has it as well, but not all the software uses it. Unless you are writing a paper about the software you should rather use the mathematical notation for the same reason we don't commonly use notation like `[i]` for subscripts, etc.

Also keep in mind that $\sim$ already has several meanings in [mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols) e.g. “is approximately equal”, “is distributed as”, “is asymptotically equivalent”, neither of them fits regression model definition.